# Not able to access web app created in eclipse with curl

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, curl

I have created a web app with eclipse. I can run it and can access it in the browser . I want to access it with curl but I am getting “404, The requested URL /de.vogella.wtp.jsp/ShowAll.jsp” was not found on this serve in response. The command I am using is

```
curl http://localhost:8080/de.vogella.wtp.jsp/ShowAll.jsp
```

Is there any setting on tomcat we have to do to access it from curl or from any java program. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you started the application?(I'm not joking)

Comment: There is no specific setting in order to access an app from CURL

Comment: Yes I have started the appllication, I can access this url from browser but not from curl. I also created a RESTful web service(Jersey) and trying to call that service from Jersey client but the same issue. I think both of these are related.

Comment: When I created a sample web app with eclipse, I started the tomcat server and index.jsp was accessible through browser. Do I have to deploy the app some other way if I want to call this web app through curl or through another java program (anything other than browser.)

Answer (score 0):

Use a proxy like [HTTPTracer](http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/HTTPTracer) to determine possible differences between the requests of your browser and curl.

Answer (score 0):

I could get the successful response from Curl when I created a war file from eclipse web project and deployed it to Tomcat. I thought running project on server (Tomcat) through eclipse was enough.

Is it necessary to export the eclipse web project and deploy it to tomcat? I believe there should be better way than this.